# Hibernate problem -- NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a NullPointerException in the following Hibernate code.  I've marked the line with the problem.  Can anyone help?

```
public List<Bulletin> searchForBulletins(String searchTerms) {
    StringTokenizer search = new StringTokenizer(searchTerms);
    String searchString = "from Bulletin where";
    /* Error in next line */
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) request.getSession()
            .getServletContext().getAttribute("sessionFactory");
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    while (search.hasMoreElements()) {
        String nextTerm = search.nextElement().toString();
        searchString += " subject like '%" + nextTerm
                + "%' or note like '%" + nextTerm + "%'";
        if (search.hasMoreElements()) {
            searchString += " or";
        }
    }
    try {
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query myQuery = session.createQuery(searchString);
        tx.commit();
        return (List<Bulletin>) myQuery.list();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}


java.lang.NullPointerException
    dao.BulletinDAO.searchForBulletins(BulletinDAO.java:195)
    action.SearchBulletins.execute(SearchBulletins.java:44)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:440)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:279)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:251)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:128)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
```

Comment: Also, it seems that NPE is not hibernate relate, but your code related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely `request` object is null. As all other elements in the expression (`request.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("sessionFactory")`) shouldn't return null according to API. But in any case you should provide a full stack trace in order to get better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Sorry I left out the stack trace.  I have edited the original message to include it.

Comment: I have solved this problem by adding request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();

Answer (score 0):

I would not use sevlet context to store the session factory. I would look at the open-session-in-view pattern for handling my hibernate sessions.

Nevertheless, if you just want to resolve the bug, I suggest breaking down that line of code and see what is actually null there, like :

```
ServletContext s= request.getSession().getServletContext();
SessionFactory sf = s.getAttribute("sessionFactory");
```